# How do I add/remove div color onclick of the div but not the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an add and remove button which selects the complete div and adds a green color to the div. The function only works on the "add this extra" and "remove" button. How do I make it work like clicking anywhere on the div instead of the particular button itself?

I would look to hear someone help from you guys.

Regards,
Bilal

```js
$('.btn_extras').addClass('force-hide');
$('.btn-rmv-item').hide();

// Add btn onClick
$('.btn-add-item').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  // Show the Adjacent Remove Button
  $(e.currentTarget).next("button.btn-rmv-item").show();
  // Apply THE DIV class to SELECTED
  $(e.currentTarget).closest("div.card-border").addClass('card-bg');
  // Show THE btn_extra button
  showHideContinueBtn();
  // Hide the Button
  $(e.currentTarget).hide();
});

// Remove btn onClick
$('.btn-rmv-item').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  // Show the Adjacent Remove Button
  $(e.currentTarget).prev("button.btn-add-item").show();
  // Apply THE DIV class to SELECTED
  $(e.currentTarget).closest("div.card-border").removeClass('card-bg');
  // Show THE btn_extra button
  showHideContinueBtn();
  // Hide the Button
  $(e.currentTarget).hide();
});

// function to Show/Hide Continue Button w.r.t SELECTIONS
function showHideContinueBtn() {
  $('.btn_extras').addClass('force-hide').removeClass('force-block');
  $('.btn_skip').removeClass('force-hide').addClass('force-block');
  $('div.card').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).hasClass('card-bg')) {
      $('.btn_extras').removeClass('force-hide').addClass('force-block');
      $('.btn_skip').removeClass('force-block').addClass('force-hide');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

.btn-add-item {
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -0.02px;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.btn-add-item:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-rmv-item {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #59d389;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -0.02px;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.btn-rmv-item:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
    <button class="btn btn-rmv-item">Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the click handler directly on the div (I assume it is `.card-border` here).

And you need only one button which you toggle the classes and change the text.

I added a `.card-bg` CSS rule that seemed to be missing in the question...
I also added `type="button"` to prevent form submission if the button is clicked.

Have a look at the comments in the code below. It **replaces** the two click handlers you had... And the `showHideContinueBtn()` function.

```js
$(".card-border").on("click",function(){

  // Toggle the div background color
  $(this).toggleClass("card-bg");
  
  // Find the button
  var btn = $(this).find(".btn");
  
  // Toggle classes for ONE button
  btn.toggleClass('btn-add-item btn-rmv-item');
  
  // Depending on a button's class, change it's text
  (btn.hasClass("btn-rmv-item"))?btn.text("Remove"):btn.text("Add this extra");
});
```

```css
.card-border {
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: 15px 18px 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

div.ho-border:hover {
  border: 1px solid #59d389;
}

.upsell-pricing {
  float: right;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.upsell-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333333;
}

.btn-add-item {
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -0.02px;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #c7c7c7;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.btn-add-item:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-rmv-item {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #59d389;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: -0.02px;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 8px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.btn-rmv-item:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

/* This class was not posted in question... So I improvised one */ 
.card-bg{
  background-color:#44bb44;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Fuel Replacement -->
<div class="card-border ho-border">
  <h4 class="float-left">Fuel replacement</h4>
  <div class="upsell-pricing">£49/trip</div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="upsell-text">Save time and return the vehicle at any fuel level. The price include upto a full tank of petrol/gas.</div>
  <div class="mt-3 float-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-add-item">Add this extra</button>
    <!--button class="btn btn-rmv-item">Remove</button-->
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see you have commented the code remove button, and tried to load via JS. I copied the same code. It works fine. But on click of "Add this extra" and remove button does not appear, and instead, it appears like this: http://prntscr.com/mwdy07

Comment: Something else in your code or CSS may be hiding it. Hit [F12] and inspect the markup... See if the button is there... Then check the CSS for it.

Comment: Hey! did you remove the `$('.btn-add-item').on('click', function(e) {` and `$('.btn-rmv-item').on('click', function(e) {` handlers ? My answer **replaces** the two and the `function showHideContinueBtn() {` (!)

Comment: Hey! It was force-hide css that was showing display:none. I have removed force-hide, force-block from css and JS too. And it works, thanks :)

Comment: Ha! Those two CSS rules weren't posted... That's why it didn't impact the snippet. ;) I edited too.

Comment: Make sure you noticed the addition of `type="button"` on the button's markup ;) That is because the default type of a button is `submit`.

Comment: I have! Cheers. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$('.btn-add-item').on('click', function(e) {
```

to

```
$(e.currentTarget).closest("div.card-border").on('click', function(e) {
```

If you want a toggle functionality, also add a variable that holds the crt state:

```
var state="default";
...on('click',function(){
    if(state=='default'){
        state='checked';
        ....
    } else {
        state='default';
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible you can add the preview, please?

Comment: Um, no, I think Stackoverflow is turning into a code writing tool, lol. As per the site rules, you are actually expected to conduct your own efforts, not for us to write your projects.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I will put my effort.

Answer (score -2):

If I understood you question right then this is answer you are looking for.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>


    <p id="demo"  onclick="myFunction()" style="width:200px; height:100px; border: 1px solid black;">
    This Div's background color will change.
    </p>

    <script>
    var color=0; 
    function myFunction() {
      // Just Specify The Id you need 
      var myDiv = document.getElementById("demo");

      if(color == 0)
      {
       myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red"; color=1;
      }
      else
      {
        myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white"; color=0;
      }
      
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope This Solves the Issue.

Comment: So I wanted the click on the div, not on the text. Any leads?

Comment: see the text content is inside the div. it need not be a text content you can give it any content inside the div and this code is still gonna work fine. and the onclick event of the div work irrespective of the content inside the div whether its an image of anything

Comment: Text content is just for the example purpose. @BillNathan. if you wish to change the color by clicking on the same div just specify the id of that div itself instead of 'demo' in the function getElementById in the script